# Can't import jaw_utils module

Tags: python, sublimetext3, maya

I'm learning Python 3 and Sublime Text 3 to work with maya. I want to import a module and it's not working.

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys

path = 'D:\MZ\Scripting\Jaw_utils'

for module_name in sys.modules.keys():
    top_module = module_name.split('.')[0]

    if top_module == 'jaw_utils':
        del(sys.modules[module_name])

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

import jaw_utils
print (jaw_utils)
```

Import error:

```
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py
line 142: No module named 'jaw_utils'
```

Comment: Just a guess, but try using `path = r'D:\MZ\Scripting\Jaw_utils'` because literal backslash characters in strings either have to be doubled *or* the whole string must prefixed with an `r` character. See ***raw strings*** in the documentation for [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: No, I got the same error

Comment: You should [edit]  your question and put the *entire* traceback in it, not just the end like you have now.